# View não renderiza após return - Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, view

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Seguinte cenário:

Tenho um botão de pesquisa no meu Layout que usa o campo text e o select para enviar dados para o javascript, que chama uma action, que chama o método do repositório para trazer os dados que preciso.

Tudo funciona, os dados são retornados, porém a View não é exibida.

A Action tem o mesmo nome da View que recebe uma List.

**Botão da chamada:**

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                            <input type="button" id="btnPesquisar" name="name" value="Pesquisar" />
                            @*<a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" onclick="javascript:FiltrarImovel();" /></a>*@
                        </div>
```

**Action:**

```
 [WebMethod]
     [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public ActionResult filtrarImovel(string texto, string filtro)
    {
        List<ImovelFiltradoViewModel> model = new List<ImovelFiltradoViewModel>();

        model = repositorio.FiltrarImovel(texto, filtro);

        model.OrderBy(i => i.ID_IMOVEL);

        TempData["ImovelFiltrado"] = model;

        return View(model.ToList());
    }
```

**View:**

```
    @model List<MeuImovel.Domain.ViewModel.ImovelFiltradoViewModel>

<h2>Imóveis</h2>
<hr />
<div class="container">
    <div class="images">
        @{foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div onclick="modal(@item.ID_IMOVEL, '@item.ENDERECO')">
                    <div class="item-content">
                        @if (item.fotos.Count > 0)
                        {
                            <img src="~/uploadeimg/@item.fotos[0].NomeAquivo" />

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <img src="~/Content/Imagens/sem_foto_icone.jpg" />
                        }

                        <div class="item-options">
                            <div>
                                <div class="address">@item.ENDERECO</div>
                                <div class="price large-text">$@string.Format("{0:n0}", item.VALOR_ALUGUEL)</div>
                                <div class="agent">
                                    <div id="@("Imóvel" + item.ID_IMOVEL)">
                                        <img src="~/Content/Imagens/iconetelefone.png">
                                        Ligue Já
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <link href="~/Content/RepeaterImoveis.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/Site.js"></script>
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$("#btnPesquisar").click(function () {

    var campoTexto = document.getElementById("textoFiltroHome").value;
    var campoLista = document.getElementById("dropFiltroHome").value;
    //alert(campoTexto + " - " + campoLista);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: 'Imoveis/filtrarImovel',
        data: {texto: campoTexto, filtro:  campoLista },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { ExecutarSucesso(data.d); },
        error: function (data) { ExecutarErro(data.d); }

    })

    function ExecutarSucesso(result) { };

    function ExecutarErro(result) { };

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi e você quer retornar uma View depois dos dados ser enviados para o Controller terá que redireccionar a para a View em caso de sucesso no seu ajax assim:

```
    success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = "/Controller/View"
  }
```